# Find all pictures and videos on given device [phonegap]

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

Been looking for three days for a tutorial on how to list every photo and video that is stored on an iOS/Android device.

The goal is to sync photos/videos to an external cloud service, but the first step is to be able to access them through Cordova.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well what would you think yourself that has to be done to know all pictures on a device?

Comment: I posted a parallel question to which there's been no feedback - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830216/reading-filesystem-using-phonegap-returns-only-a-single-object

Comment: You are trying that with javascript. And you still want to use phonegap and javascript? That runs in a browser isn't it? The browser isn't supposed to have access to the file system. Only some very specifuc webfolders.

Comment: How can we have access to all media files using phonegap?